# Where to put VLAN interface

Tags: linux, debian, linux-networking, proxmox

I have a Proxmox VE 7.4 installed on a server (that's debian 11-based distro).

On this server I have 2 x 1 Gbps network interfaces. On top of them i have Linux bond (LACP mode, but probably unimportant here). Then, on top of bond0 I have Linux bridge vmbr0, that is "VLAN aware". vmbr0 is primarily used for VM-s. A VLAN interface will be used to access the host (host management) and it needs to be in another VLAN.

Where should I put a Linux VLAN interface for host management ? There's basically 3 ways to do it, I can:

- put it on a bond0 (with bond0.VLAN_ID)
- put it on vmbr0 (with vmbr0.VLAN_ID)
- install a separate Linux VLAN interface (vlanX) with raw device that is either bond0 or vmbr0.

bond0 seemed like the place to put it on and so I did. But then, if I have a default gateway on that interface, it doesn't work - the system doesn't see or use that gateway (and has no Internet access) although I can access the host via that VLAN. Why def gw doesn't work in that case, I have no clue.

If I instead put a VLAN interface on vmbr0 then everything works, including having a default gateway there. So, sure, I can just go on with that - but. I'm here because I need some expert help to understand ***why*** putting a VLAN on one interface or the other is better/preferred/etc and why it doesn't work if I put it directly on bond0 ?

Anyways, where would you put it ? Which way should be preferred and why.

Thanks in advance :)

Comment: just a suggestion, proxmox has a really great forum and the vendor also goes into community support, so I think you would be better answered there

Comment: Thank you. I might ask there as well, but this is not proxmox specific.

Comment: Reposted here: https://forum.proxmox.com/threads/where-to-actually-put-a-vlan-interface.129670